# online ftp with automatic login

Tags: php, html

I had a question,
I am a beginner html and a very small php writer,
And I have some kind of online ftp client so have a download site on my site that I can do, for example, in filezilla a folder and you can upload files and you can view and download that site, does anyone have an idea? Or a cool download that I can use for it, it must be true that you do not have to inteloggen so you do not have to enter all the ftp data on the site but just get it right in that folder for the FTP online.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not clear completely.

If I understand you then, you want to create filezilla by php which will work on browser.

First create database with ftp login details and column which user will use this. Once user login set a token and authenticate  properly.

After login fetch ftp login details from database and connect to server.

Everytime User send or receive file you have to query ftp login details and then do other stuff, same as before.